# Get user location: Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, location

So I have searched the internet for lots of different solutions to get my android phone to show current location through the Google Maps API using play services. I believe I have the right set-up but something is just not right.

Please see below the .java and .xml code.

Java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private UiSettings mUiSettings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment
                = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    }

    private void centerMapOnMyLocation() {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location location = mMap.getMyLocation();

        // Getting latitude
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latlng;

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            //Create a LatLng object for the current location
            latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, (LocationListener) this);
        }

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="example.navigationapplication_10.MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Many thanks

Comment: There are a lot of potential issues. Firstly, you need to make sure you have the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission in your Manifest. Secondly, if you're developing on Android API 23, you're going to have to implement the check self permissions block so that you can get the permission to access location. Also note that if location comes out null, you will have exceptions when declaring "double latitude" and "double longitude". In addition, GoogleMap.getMyLocation() is deprecated, refer to https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#public-methods

Answer (score 2):

Try using this class to get the Latitude and Longitude..

```
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {


private Context context;

boolean isGPSEnabled=false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled=false;
boolean canGetLocation=false;

Location location;

double latitude;
double longitude;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES=10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES=1000*60*1;

protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context)
{
    this.context=context;
getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation()
{
    try{
    locationManager=(LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);




    if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
    {
        showSettingsAlert();
    }
    else{
        this.canGetLocation=true;
        if(isNetworkEnabled)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);


        if(locationManager !=null)
        {
            location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(location !=null)
        {
            latitude=location.getLatitude();
            longitude=location.getLongitude();
        }
        }
        }

        if(isGPSEnabled){
            if(location==null)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if(locationManager !=null)
                {
                    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    if(location !=null)
                    {
                        latitude=location.getLatitude();
                        longitude=location.getLongitude();
                    }   

                }

            }
        }


    }


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location;
}

public void stopUsingGPS()
{
    if(locationManager !=null)
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

public double getLatitude()
{
    if(location!=null)
    {
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
    }
    return latitude;

}


public double getLongitude()
{
    if(location!=null)
    {
        longitude=location.getLongitude();
    }
    return longitude;

}

public boolean canGetLocation(){

return this.canGetLocation;

}

public void showSettingsAlert(){
    Builder alertDialog=new Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled.Do you want to go to the settings menu?");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); 

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


}
```

And for marking your position in the map

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
GPSTracker gps;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;



    try {

        gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);

        if (gps.canGetLocation) {
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("I am here"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

            for(int i=0;i<MainActivity.nameArray.length;i++)
            {
                latitude=Double.parseDouble(MainActivity.latArray[i]);
                longitude=Double.parseDouble(MainActivity.lonArray[i]);
                LatLng shops = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(shops).title(MainActivity.nameArray[i]));

            }





        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

}

Hope this Helps